# Yarn packages not found

Tags: yarnpkg

I have Yarn 2.4.0 
I used `yarn add @mikro-orm/core` to install the package.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "dependencies": {
    "@mikro-orm/core": "^4.3.2"
  }
}
```

When I try to do something like:

```
const mikroORM = require("@mikro-orm/core");

const orm = mikroORM.MikroORM.init();
```

I get an error pointing to the import statement with:

```
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
```

This happens with other packages as well.
What might be the problem here?

Comment: This seems like a network issue. What do you get for `yarn info @mikro-orm/core`

Comment: yarn info @mikro-orm/core
└─ @mikro-orm/core@npm:4.3.2
   ├─ Instances: 1
   ├─ Version: 4.3.2
   │
   └─ Dependencies<br>
      ├─ ansi-colors@npm:4.1.1 → npm:4.1.1
      ├─ clone@npm:2.1.2 → npm:2.1.2
      ├─ escaya@npm:0.0.61 → npm:0.0.61
      ├─ fs-extra@npm:9.0.1 → npm:9.0.1
      ├─ globby@npm:11.0.1 → npm:11.0.1
      ├─ reflect-metadata@npm:0.1.13 → npm:0.1.13
      └─ strip-json-comments@npm:3.1.1 → npm:3.1.1

Comment: Is the module installed in the `node_modules` directory of the current working directory? `test -d node_modules/@mikro-orm/core && echo YES || echo NO`

Comment: That is the problem! `node_modules` does not exist in the project. Why would that happen and how can I add it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `yarn` to install the node_modules specified in the package.json.

Comment: I ran the command, but nothing happened. `node_modules` still doesn't exist.

Comment: huh interesting... Will you try `npm install @mikro-orm/core` instead

Comment: That fixes the problem. Should I try reinstall Yarn?

Comment: Awesome! There must be some issue with yarn or your package.json configuration. Hard to say without more info.